# Background don't fill the entire section

Tags: html, css

I'm using this template( http://www.display-inline.fr/demo/developr/template/inbox.html ) in one test project, but, when I change section `<section role="main" id="main">` to use the class `carbon` the background is not full filled.

I tried to resize the section using `style='height: 100%'`, but, not worked.
How I can fill the entire page with the carbon class background ?

Comment: Can you provide some code?  Read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I can't, because the problem is just happening with this template....

Answer (score 0):

instead of using `height:100%` you should use `height:100vh`

```css
.wrapper {
  background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/fhEwl.png");
  height: 100vh;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">text</div>
```